# How to show and close plot in matplitlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I have a real-time updating pandas dataframe with two columns of coordinates. I want to use geopandas to insert a shapefile map in jupyter notebook as a background, and plot the real time coordinates in the map in every 5 seconds, without closing and opening the background map every time. Here are the simplified codes.

```
geo_data.plot(alpha=0,figsize=(12, 12))

plt.ion()
while True:
    plt.figure()
    for i in range(len(paths)):
        plt.plot(paths.ix[i:i+1,'z'],paths.ix[i:i+1,'x'])
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(5)
    plt.close()
```

However the "close" doesn't work. It plots one graph after one. I also tried to change the places of "ion", "show", "sleep" and "close" in and out side the "while" loop. None of them is working.

In a word, the geopandas map should be static in the plot. And the real-time coordinates data refreshes on top of the map every five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

just add plt.clear() at the end instead of plt.close(). It will replace your old plot and bring the new one on top of it.

Comment: it dosen't work. I tried `plt.gcf().clear()` as well. dosen't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [plt.clf()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf) instead of plt.close(). It keeps the plot open but clears it so it can be used for a new plot.